# Singleton object initialized several times at Typhoon Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

I have issue where singleton object has few instances while using typhoon auto-injection pattern.

In my example there are 2 view controllers, which has their own models, and this models should use singleton instance of third model. I'm developing storyboard-based application without storyboard integration with typhoon but with with [plist integration](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Plist-Integration).

Here is my assembly file:

```
#pragma mark - Singletons
- (id<AccountManager>)accountManager {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[AccountManagerImpl class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
    }];
}

#pragma mark - ViewController Models
- (VideoListModel *)childVideoListModel {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[VideoListModel class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithAccountManager:)
                        parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
                            [initializer injectParameterWith:[self accountManager]];
                        }];
    }];
}

- (LoginModel *)loginModel {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[LoginModel class]     configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithAccountManager:)
                        parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
                            [initializer injectParameterWith:[self accountManager]];
                        }];
    }];
}
```

And in my viewControllers I get models using auto-injection:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) InjectedClass(VideoListModel) model;
```

and the same with another viewController. And when I access accountManager from VideoListModel and LoginModel, it has different instances for it.

What I'm doing wrong? Or probably I have missed something in typhoon configuration?

**UPD:** actually it looks like when I use auto-injection, it injects models from different instances of ModelsAssembly.

Comment: At runtime assemblies are just a proxy for TyphoonComponentFactory, and it sounds like somehow you've ended up with 2 of these. Can you post your whole assemblies? Another Typhoon user had this happen once when they accidentally intantiated an assembly from inside another assembly. (They actually wanted to just declare a property for a collaborating assembly)

Comment: @JasperBlues it looks like I understand problem while creating demo app :)
In one place I present viewController not using segues, but manually creating it from storyboard using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. Thats why I have different assembly for it, am I right?

Comment: In most (all typical) cases you'll have one TyphoonComponentFactory per application. If you've still got more then one, something is not right. Can you show a) How Typhoon is instantiated b) How your view controller is obtained from Typhoon.